# Can Dropwizard pick up hibernate config from hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard

I am new to DropWizard and so far am loving it. I have got it up and running fairly easily with hibernate by configuring my database properties in my application.yml file:

```
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: dev
  password: dev
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev
```

However, on our server environments we already have a number of applications running using hibernate that are configured via a hibernate.cfg.xml file. It would be nice to reuse this file for my application, rather than having to duplicate the settings in the application.yml file on every environment.

Is it possible to get Dropwizard to create the hibernate bundle from hibernate.cfg.xml instead of yaml? If so, how?